# Asp query string for url change with access db

Tags: asp-classic

We have an oldish website with an access db just holding simple products against categories

When a menu category is clicked on the front end the url structure looks like:

```
ourcompany.com/products.asp?cat=category+name+here
```

So the plus sign is used to fill any blanks to pass the variable through to query the db simply

We have been told to change the plus signs to minus signs as google finds this more seo friendly but when testing, the minus sign does not work. Link doesnt work

Has anyone any suggestions how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the category name in the database to match the URL, so change it to minus signs. Alternatively, you can replace the minus signs in ASP with plus signs before query-ing the database.
If I'm not mistaken the + sign in a URL is translated into a space by default, so the browser already does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

SEO discussion aside, the query string you posted:

```
ourcompany.com/products.asp?cat=category+name+here
```

will end up giving `Request.QueryString("cat")` the value of `category name here` - note that the spaces are URL encoded as plus signs.

If you wanted

```
ourcompany.com/products.asp?cat=category-name-here
```

You would either need to change the server-side code to filter out the new "-" in the category name, or you would need to change the name of the category itself to include the new "-".